# How to force a css grid with grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(x,y)) to distribute items as equally as possible on every row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm building a css grid. The css looks like:

```
div.stats {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));
    }
```

While the html has exactly 6 items:

```
<div class=stats>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
    <div>Item 6</div>
</div>
```

While looking it at from a phone, this provides a nice 2 columns layout:

```
| Item1 | Item2 |
| Item3 | Item4 |
| Item5 | Item6 |
```

Looking at it with a widescreen (pc or horizontal tablet), it provides a nice 6 columns layout:

```
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5 | Item6 |
```

But looking at it horizontally from phone it has 5 items on the first row and 1 on the second:

```
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5 |
| Item6 |
```

And looking at it vertically from a large screen (like a tablet) it has 4 items of the first row and 2 on the second:

```
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 |
| Item5 | Item6 |
```

Is there a way to tell the css to always try to have the same number of items in each row, so to have 3 items both in the first and the second row when viewing from the "middle ground" screens?

```
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
| Item4 | Item5 | Item6 |
```

I tried every possible combination I could think of: auto-fill, minmax(3fr, 1fr) which obviously doesn't work, % values, adding various grid-template-rows values, including masonry, etc.

Comment: You want it to always be 2 X 2 or 3 X 3 like that?

Comment: I want it to adapt: 1x6 if on a wide screen; 2x3 if on a narrow screen; and 3x2 if on a "middle ground" screen.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, in the "middle ground" you can use the below CSS.

```
.stats {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
```

And other cases like the mobile screen you can use the below CSS.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .stats {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }
}
```

Your code like this

```css
.stats {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .stats {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=stats>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
    <div>Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Now you resize your screen and show output on the mobile and desktop screen and also you can add more items in Html and change column count in the CSS for your requirements.